# AngularJS — Explicitly returning a value from a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I ran into the codeblock below the other day, and I am trying to figure out why exactly the author may have chosen to `return init();` rather than doing something like

```
$scope.init = function() {...};
```

And calling it with an `ng-click`, or something or other. 
Here's the code:

```
myApp.controller("PlaylistCtrl", [
  "$scope", "tracksService", function($scope, tracksService) {
    var init;
    init = function() {
      $scope.addTrack("Jay-Z - 99 Problems");
      return $scope.tracks = $scope.getTracks();
    };
    $scope.getTracks = function() {
      return tracksService.tracks();
    };
    $scope.addTrack = function(trackTitle) {
      if (trackTitle !== "") {
        return tracksService.addTrack(trackTitle);
      }
    };
    return init();
  }
]);
```

So the question as stands is: what is the purpose of returning a value from a controller? What additional functionality does it exploit? Is this causing `init()` to be ran once the controller is initiated—if not, what is the specific purpose here? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The return value of the controller is the controller object instance-of a PlaylistCtrl. So you may add properties and methods to attach to the 'returned value' of the controller rather than attaching them to the inherited $scope variable. See http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific meaning to it and as is removing the `return` wouldn't change anything.

If you look at the other functions, it seems that that developper has the habit to return from every function, even when not necessary.

That is probably just a habit. In somes instances it could help a developper make sure that is the end of the initializations block, putting the functions declarations below, such as in this small example:

```
// Initialization
var foo = 'bar';
doFoo();
doBar();

return; // <- end of declarative block

// Methods
function doFoo() { ... }
function doBar() { ... }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvJdn/158/
In this fiddle, it seems that ```init()``` is causing the init function to be ran upon initiation (notice how ```{{tracks}}``` is populated—without returning ```init()``` wouldn't you explicitly have to attach ```init``` to the ```$scope``` and use ```ng-click``` or something or other to get ```init()``` to run?

Comment: I'm not super confortable with this syntax (CoffeScript?) but I can assure you no, returning `init()` or not won't have any effect on the Angular cycle. But calling it does of course. `init()` is executed by the controller, which means as soon as the application is compiled (or bootstrated) by Angular, hence `{{tracks}}` is populated. You don't need to trigger anything to have a controller run its code.